# ERROR: Plugin 'Echo' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am trying to develop a custom plugin referring to

https://github.com/apache/cordova-docs/blob/master/www/docs/en/dev/guide/platforms/ios/plugin.md

Though it's a standard/straightforward  way of implementing a custom plugin in Cordova I am getting this error

```
2016-08-28 20:39:23.460 customPlugin[6618:3992671] ERROR: Plugin 'Echo' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2016-08-28 20:39:23.460 customPlugin[6618:3992671] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 142] FAILED pluginJSON = ["Echo1913903636","Echo","Echo",[]]
```

In config.xml mapping is done.
In Xcode Echo.h and Echo.m files are placed under classes folder.

From javascript, after device ready event, I am trying to call the custom plugin with following code where Echo is the name of the native method.

cordova.exec(successFn,errorFn, 'Echo', 'Echo', []);

I am not sure whats going wrong.
Any suggestions for this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your `plugin.xml`?

Comment: The above tutorial did not mention about plugin.xml. I suppose it to be config.xml under the project root directory.                                  <feature name="Echo">
    <param name="ios-package" value="Echo" />
</feature>    Please let me know if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `plugin.xml` in the root of your plugin project. This missing file is what looks like to be causing the error. Make sure you're following the [tutorial](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html#building-a-plugin).